# How can I loop through objects in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, loops, object, swift2

I have the following object:

(rates)

```
{
  EUR: "1"
  RON: 4.5
  USD: 1.3
  .
  .
  .
  n: INT/STRING
}
```

Is there any function that does this?

Comment: There are both loops and higher-order functions to choose from. What to choose depends on what you want to accomplish. Have you read [the guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html)?

Comment: I did. Still not found the solution. So what should I do? Any other methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's a dictionary, no enumerate() required:

```
var aDictionary: [String: Float] = ["EUR": 1, "RON": 4.5,
    "USD": 1.3]

for (index,item) in aDictionary{
    print(index,item)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you care about the index, you can use a 'traditional' for loop - although @Eric points out this will soon be completely removed

```
for var i = 0; i < rates.count; i++
{
   let rate = rates[i]
   // do stuff with rate
}
```

The enumerate approach looks like this

```
for (index, rate) in rates.enumerate() 
{
    print("Do stuff with \(rate) at position \(index)")
}
```

if you just need each object in turn it's a bit easier

```
for rate in rates
{
    // do stuff with rate
}
```

Comment: `for var ... i++` loops (C-style loops) are deprecated in Swift 2.2 and will be removed from Swift 3. For looping with an index use .enumerate() on the sequence.

Comment: The joy of continuous updates to Swift :-)

Edited the answer to include this

Comment: Guys thanks for your help! Now I get an error: "Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'enumerate'"

Comment: Another thing... to use an object from the rates, i have to use    rates.objectForKey("EUR") . Maybe this helps

Comment: @CodeContrive - if you're going to pick out values based on the key, then you don't need to loop through the array.

Comment: I know.. but I want to loop through them. Isn't there a function like... objectForIndex(number)

Comment: @CodeContrive - each of the options above does exactly that.  If you need the index - to link up with other data, perhaps - then use one of the forms that includes index.  if everything you need is included in the object itself, go for the simple 'for rate in rates' style